# General relativity -- How are components of $ds^2$ specified?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

Suppose we take $M$ to denote the spacetime manifold. Suppose also that $ds^2 = g_{\mu \nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu $. I have some confusions with regards to the metric and the line elements.

My main confusion is at which points in the manifold are $ds^2$ defined? Is it correct that if $p \in M$, then it only makes sense to fix $ds^2$ for each tangent space $T_pM$, or is it fixed for each $v \in T_pM$? More specifically:

1. If there is some position dependent line element, such as the Schwartzschild line element, then $g_{\mu \nu}= g_{\mu \nu}(t,r, \theta, \phi) $. Are these $(t,r, \theta, \phi)$ the coordinates of some $(t,r, \theta, \phi) \in M$, or are they the coordinates of some $ (t,r, \theta, \phi) \in T_pM $?
2. Are the differentials $dx^\mu(a)$ evaluated at each $a \in M$ or $a \in T_pM$?
3. Since all vectors are elements in some tangent space, it seems to me that for 4-dimensional spacetime we would need to specify 8 coordinates to make precise which vector we are talking about. The first 4 coordinates would specify the tangent space, and the last 4 coordinates would specify the vector inside of the tangent space. However, when I try and do exercises, only 4 coordinates are given. Are the remaining 4 coordinates given implicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) When we call something *coordinates* in this context, they always refer to coordinates in $M$. A *tensor field* is a function from $M$ to a tensor bundle, so the coefficients $g_{\mu\nu}$ are functions of points of $M$. If you coordinatize $M$, then you can view the coefficients as functions of the coordinates. So the coordinates $(t,r,\vartheta,\varphi)$ are labels for points of $M$, NOT $T_pM$.

2) The differentials are *covectors*, which, like vectors are associated with points of $M$. So $dx^\mu(p)$ is evaluated at a point of $M$.

3) You are right, and that is what the previous answer (the one you dismissed) referred to.
To give an arbitrary vector of $M$, you need to specify 8 coordinates, coordinates of a point $p$, and the *components* of a vector **at** $p$.

You can say that $M$ is a 4-dimensional manifold, yo it can be coordinatized by 4 coordinates, and we have the tangent bundle $TM$, which can be seen as the set of all vectors of $M$. The tangent bundle is a 8 dimensional manifold, because a point of $TM$ (which is a vector of $M$) can be specified by giving the tuple $(p,v)$, where **explicitly** $p$ is described by the manifold coordinates and $v$ is described by the vector components taken with respect to the manifold coordinates.

When you do exercises, it depends on the exercise. If you are given a vector in the form $V^\mu=(\cos(\varphi),r^2e^{-r}\sin(\vartheta),0,0)$, for example, then you are actually given a **vector field**. Here the manifold points are implicit. If you want to ask what is the value of $V$ at the point $(t,r,\vartheta,\varphi)$, you *insert* the desired values of the coordinates into the functional expression, then the vector you get is the vector that is located at the point $p$ whose coordinates you have given.

If you are given a vector $v^\mu=(1,2,-5,4)$ for example, then either this is a vector field that has constant components in you coordinate system, or the exercise needs to specify a point $p$ of $M$ where this vector is located. Either case, you actually have 8 numbers. 4 for a point and 4 for components.

---

Lastly, here's a note that might clear some of your confusion:

What do we mean under coordinates?

In the context of vector spaces, we often say that if $e_1,...,e_n$ is a basis of $V$, then if we give $x=x^1e_1+...x^ne_n$, then the numbers $x^1,...,x^n$ are the coordinates of the vector $x$. It is because if we view $V$ as a space of positions, then technically speaking this "*linear algebraic coordinate system*" is also a coordinate system in the manifold sense.

But in physics we usually have two kinds of vectors. One that points between two points (position/separation vectors) and one that has a direction and magnitude, but which sits comfortably at a single point. The latter case, we almost never say that "coordinates of a vector", we say "components of a vector", because the latter kind of vector can never denote a spatial position.

In differential geometry, we only have one kind of vector, and its the latter case, eg. vectors **at** points.

So in differential geometric language, when we say coordinates, we mean labels that denote points of the manifold. When we say *components*, we mean the expansion coefficients of pointwise-defined linear objects (vectors, tensors, spinors, connections etc.) in some given basis.

These two concepts can be unified, precisely by the use of bundles. Imagine we have a point $p$ whose coordinates are $(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)$ and a vector $v$ at the point $p$, whose components are $(v^0,v^1,v^2,v^3)$.

Then from the point of view of "bundle-less differential geometry", the labels $(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)$ are **coordinates**, but the labels $(v^0,v^1,v^2,v^3)$ are **components**.

On the other hand, if we switch to the tangent bundle $TM$, then we can say that the 8-component tuple $(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3,v^0,v^1,v^2,v^3)$ are **coordinates** of the tangent bundle, because fro mthe point of view of the tangent bundle, the vector $v$ at $p\in M$ is a **point** of $TM$, and **not a vector** of $TM$.

Answer (score 0):

A point $p=(t,r, \theta, \phi)$ can be seen as an element of $M$. Note that $T_pM$ denotes the tangent space at $p$ whose elements are tangent vectors, so there is no sense $p$ is an element of $T_pM$.

One can say however the tuple $(p, v)$ consisting of a point and a vector is an element of the tangent *bundle* $TM$. However, in most mathematical literature, we often identify $T_pM$ with its image under the canonical injection $v \mapsto (p,v)$ and context may determine what notation is most appropriate to consider for an element of the tanegnt bundle.

Comment: Was my question unclear? I am not asking if p is in TpM.